# Derivative of $X_u A X B X_u^T$ w.r.t. $X_u$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to solve this $\frac{d X_u A X B X_u^T}{d X_u}$, where $X, A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $X_u$ is the $u$-th row in $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_u(X)=X_uAXBX_u^\mathrm{T}$ and $X_u=\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}X$ where $\mathbf{e}_u=(\delta_{iu})^{\mathrm{T}}_{1\le i\le n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (only the $u$-th entry is 1 and others are 0). We have

\begin{align*}
&\frac{d\,X_uAXBX_u^\mathrm{T}}{dX}\\
=&\frac{d\,\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}XAXBX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u}{dX}\\
=&\frac{d\,\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}XAXBX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u)}{dX}\\
=&\frac{d\,\mathrm{tr}(XAXBX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T})}{dX}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
&d\,\mathrm{tr}(XAXBX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T})\\
=&\mathrm{tr}\left(dX\cdot A XB X^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}\right)
+\mathrm{tr}\left(XA \cdot dX\cdot BX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}\right)
+\mathrm{tr}\left(XA XB\cdot d(X^\mathrm{T})\cdot\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}\right)\\
=&\mathrm{tr}\left(A XB X^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}\cdot dX\right)
+\mathrm{tr}\left(BX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}XA \cdot dX\right)
+\mathrm{tr}\left(B^\mathrm{T}X^\mathrm{T}A^\mathrm{T}X^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}\cdot dX\right)
\end{align*}
So
$$
\frac{d\,X_uAXBX_u^\mathrm{T}}{dX}=AXBX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}+BX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}XA+B^\mathrm{T}X^\mathrm{T}A^\mathrm{T}X^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}
$$

The derivative $df_u(X)/dX$ maps $dX$ to $df_u(X)$ by $df_u(X)=\mathrm{tr}(df_u(X)/dX\cdot dX)$.

To calculate $df_u(X)/dX_u$, we only allow the $u$-th row of $dX$ non-zero. Then only the $u$-th column of $df_u(X)/dX$ can contribute to $df_u(X)$. So $df_u(X)/dX_u=$ the $u$-th column of $df_u(X)/dX$.

I did some simulations in Python as well:

```
import numpy as np


def f(X, u, A, B):
    Xu = X[u, :]
    return Xu @ A @ X @ B @ Xu.T


def f_grad(X, u, A, B):
    n = X.shape[0]
    eu_eu_T = np.zeros((n, n))
    eu_eu_T[u, u] = 1
    part1 = A @ X @ B @ X.T @ eu_eu_T
    part2 = B @ X.T @ eu_eu_T @ X @ A
    part3 = B.T @ X.T @ A.T @ X.T @ eu_eu_T
    return part1 + part2 + part3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 4
    A = np.random.randn(n, n)
    B = np.random.randn(n, n)
    X = np.random.randn(n, n)
    u = 1
    eps = 1e-8

    grad = f_grad(X, u, A, B)
    f_X = f(X, u, A, B)

    for i in range(20):
        dXu = np.random.randn(n) * eps
        dX = np.zeros((n, n))
        dX[u, :] = dXu
        df_a = np.dot(grad[:, u], dXu)
        df_e = f(X + dX, u, A, B) - f_X
        print('df_a = %g\tdf_e = %g' % (df_a, df_e))
```

One can see that `df_a` (`a` for "analytical") is roughly the same as `df_e` (`e` for "empirical").

Comment: @Ahmed Hussein I cannot find you previous comment but I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it as I noticed that you edited your answer. I am currently thinking about your work and comparing it to mine. I think I misunderstood the question. Can you please explain why a $\text{tr}$ suddenly appeared in the derivation?

Comment: @AhmedHussein (I left out a transposition and I added it back) it is like $df=\nabla f\cdot dx$ for vectors.

Comment: One question, how to get  from $\mathrm{tr}\left(XA \cdot dX\cdot BX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}\right)$ to $\mathrm{tr}\left(BX^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{e}_u\mathbf{e}_u^\mathrm{T}XA \cdot dX\right)$? [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)(Eq. 70) states differently:$\frac{\sigma a^T X b}{\sigma X} = ab^T$. Am I missing some point?

Comment: @xiaohan2012 Since $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: @xiaohan2012 There are two conventions of layouts. This book is probably using the other one according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#cite_note-matrix-cookbook-5). If using his convention, you need to transpose the matrix when moving the $d$ from outside the trace to inside, and add a second transposition in the derivative mapping such that $df_u(X)=\mathrm{tr}((df_u(X)/dX)^\mathrm{T}\cdot dX)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Cartesian column vector $e_u$, the row vector can be written as $$X_u=e_u^TX$$
Use the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to write the function and its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= XAXBX^T:e_ue_u^T \cr
df &= (dX\,AXBX^T + XA\,dX\,BX^T + XAXB\,dX^T):e_ue_u^T \cr
   &= (e_ue_u^TXB^TX^TA^T + A^TX^Te_ue_u^TXB^T + e_ue_u^TXAXB):dX \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}:dX\big),\,$ the gradient wrt $X$ is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= e_ue_u^TXB^TX^TA^T + A^TX^Te_ue_u^TXB^T + e_ue_u^TXAXB \cr
}$$
To find the gradient wrt $X_u$, multiply the matrix gradient by $e_u^T$
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_u} &= e_u^T\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \cr
   &= e_u^Te_ue_u^TXB^TX^TA^T + e_u^TA^TX^Te_ue_u^TXB^T + e_u^Te_ue_u^TXAXB \cr
   &= X_uB^TX^TA^T + e_u^TA^TX_u^TX_uB^T + X_uAXB \cr
}$$